# Has Cordova App on OSX way to run shell command?

Tags: macos, cordova, ionic3

I'm trying to create an OSX app with Ionic3 (Cordova).

Now, I want to run any command or script and obtain its output with a callback.
However, I didn't find any sample code, document or tip helps me on the internet.

Do you know any resolution or information?

By the way, with this platform, I'm creating Unity Launcher same as Epic Launcher. Now, I've already made it zsh-zaw version. So, I want to wrap it with GUI and publish it on github.